# Opening a stuck hood in Ford Fiesta mk6

Tags: ford, car, hood

First of all I'm new to this sub stackexchange, and an even more of a noob when it comes to car maintenance or repair, so please be patient.

I have a Ford Fiesta mk6, and the hood just won't open now. I did some research, and it looks like the hood release cable has failed. Not sure if broken or just popped out, or smth.

I tried to open the hood like as shown in [videos](https://youtu.be/xMrjwUfdiiE) But cannot find the release mechanism. I'm pretty sure I pushed on every single part of the release mechanism, but no luck. I can only move the closing lever.

This is the locking/opening mechanism.

[image: This is the locking/opening mechanism]

This is what used to pop out when the "open hood" lever was pulled

[image]

So my question is: How can I open the hood now? Where is the opening mechanism located? Can anybody see what I should do to open my hood?

Answer (score 1):

[image]Best I can tell, the part with the green line is a metal loop attached to your hood. The red line points to a "hook" that grabs that loop and holds the hood closed.  If you can figure out how to get the hook to move you should be able to lift the hood.

*Edit: Added the light blue. Perhaps making that part of the mechanism move in the direction of the arrow will move the "hook" part. Be sure that there isn't a lot of upward pressure on the hood - that might make moving the hook out of the way difficult*

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. Should I be looking for a cord, or maybe some lever?

Comment: Make a J-shaped hook out of a piece of wire clothes hanger, and push it in where the open hood lever emerges (or used to emerge) from under the front lip of the hood. Maneuver the hook to catch on the light blue lever. Pull.